# Should pm.se deal with company / startup questions?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed an increased appearance on PM.SE questions (such [THIS](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/26077/430), [THIS](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/26050/430) and [THIS](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/26079/430)) related to how to manage not only a project, but more strategic program (or even company) wide questions.

As of today, these questions have nowhere else around StackExchange to be a good fit. Being the case (I believe) there's a considerable amount of PMs here who also deal with such problems, would it be the interest of the community to also consider such questions on-topic?

In the past, similar questions could be discussed on Startup proposals, but they ([Startups](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62811/startups) and [Startup business](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business)) failed to engage enough audience and good content.

**Edit:** Interesting enough, some questions (like [THIS](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/25945/430)) are clearly about how to deal with vendors at company level and still on-topic.

Worth to highlight I'm **NOT** proposing to *repurpose* pm.se. I want to hear from the community if covering this area is something that could be acceptable to only then, IF there's engagement and community believes there's a LOT of overlapping, to discuss with SE team.

Answer (score 2):

Questions can have *overlap* with other topics besides the project management domain. However, if a question is not squarely on-topic regarding the practice or profession of project management then it should be closed as off-topic for PMSE.

The fact that the question might not be a current fit elsewhere on SE is irrelevant to determining whether the question is on topic *here*. Such questions should be handled on their individual merits and topicality. Helpful comments (not answers) that point to other resources or offer suggestions are not out of line for off-topic questions, though.